# Angular POST request been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cors

I have already set cors on the backend , I just dont know why I am receiving 404 error when the url is correct. The error is Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3008/api/vehicle' from origin 'http://localhost:3007' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. I have also added my api cross domain below. please check the sample code below.What would be the solution to this problem ? what causes this issues ?I have already set cors on the backend , I just dont know why I am receiving 404 error when the url is correct. The error is Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3008/api/vehicle' from origin 'http://localhost:3007' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. I have also added my api cross domain below. please check the sample code below.What would be the solution to this problem ? what causes this issues ?

Any idea?

## Http post service

```
save(vehicle: Vehicle){

    return this.http.post(

        CONSTANST.routes.person.save,
        {
            Stock: vehicle.Stock,
            VIN: vehicle.VIN,
            age: vehicle.age,
            gender: vehicle.gender,
        },                
    );
}
```

## routes

```
const HOST ='http://localhost:3008'

export const CONSTANST = {
    permissions:{},
    routes:{
        authorization:{
            login: HOST + '/api/app/signin-email',
            logout: HOST + '/api/auth/logout'
        },
        person:{
            list: HOST + '/api/vehicle',
            save: HOST + '/api/vehicle',
        },
        user: {}
    },
    lang:{},
    session:{},
    parameters:{}
};
```

## api cross domain request

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    console.log('------------------------------------------------');
    console.log('Notice: Enabling CORS for development.');
    console.log('------------------------------------------------');
    app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        next();
    });
}
```

## api routes

```
app.get('/api/vehicle',  keystone.middleware.api, routes.api.vehicle.list);
    app.post('/api/vehicle',  keystone.middleware.api ,routes.api.vehicle.create);
```

Comment: the port of UI and the API is different. So it will be blocked by browser security. The API has to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with value of `*` or `http://localhost:3007` to bypass this

Comment: please show your backend cors config here...

Comment: I would like to recommend to use Angular proxy config( https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md ) instead of direct API call using complete URL during the development. Once you added proxy, you do not need to add host like `HOST + `

Comment: so what would be the solution ?

Comment: @ArifKhan , what is the disadvantage of directly calling api using complete URL ?

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya , They are on a seperate port because i am running them seperately , the front end will just consume the url of the api

Comment: "The API has to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with value of `*` or `http://localhost:3007` to bypass this"

Comment: I have updated my question above ,  I have added the cross domain in the api

Comment: the main error is zone.js:3331 OPTIONS http://localhost:3008/api/vehicle 404 (Not Found) althought the url is correct

Comment: `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');`

Comment: do i need to add that to the back end ?

Comment: same , same error OPTIONS http://localhost:3008/api/vehicle 404 (Not Found) , Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3008/api/vehicle' from origin 'http://localhost:3007' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 0):

In your case url can be correct, but you have no configured handler for "OPTIONS" requests method in your api routes. It should be configured like you do it for GET or POST requests. And as result you receiving 404 response on your preflight requests.

```
app.options('/api/vehicle',  keystone.middleware.api ,routes.api.vehicle.create);
```

But you do not need pass there your callback with logic because you will execute your logic twice.

In addition i can advice you to do one options handler for all your routes:

```
app.options('*', someSimpleCallback);
```

Comment: #Slovy  , I have a question Sir

Comment: Is the problem on the server side or the the client side ?

Comment: Server side. You are sending GET request to receive vehicles list and POST request to create this one. But browser before each your request will send OPTIONS request on this url to check permissions to send crossdomain requests on those urls. As result, you should to configure OPTIONS requests handler on the servfer side: 
app.options('/api/vehicle',  keystone.middleware.api ,routes.api.vehicle.create);

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing a trailing slash after the id of object I wanted to delete.

If you're using Django Rest Framework for backend, ensure that you've set the [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/advanced/#topics-testing-advanced-multiple-hosts). You may also want to use [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers.) app.